# Only one of the materials gets added when importing from GLTF

Tags: texturing, gltf

I have a GLTF file with two materials, each with a texture. There is only one mesh. However, when I import the file into Blender, only one material is available.

I imagine that the issue is that the second material isn't assigned to any mesh. I want to have two materials available for the same mesh and be able to switch between them somehow (for example, one texture that looks like grass while the other texture looks like metal, covering the whole model). Is there any way to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the problem by adding a duplicate of the mesh and associating the second material with it. Not quite what I wanted, but it works now.